# How to add custom renames in six?

Tags: python, six

According to the documentation, six supports [adding custom renames](http://pythonhosted.org//six/#advanced-customizing-renames) to [`six.moves`](http://pythonhosted.org//six/#module-six.moves):

> **`six.add_move(item)`**
>
> Add item to the `six.moves` mapping. item should be a `MovedAttribute` or
>   `MovedModule` instance.

And:

> `class six.MovedModule(name, old_mod, new_mod)`
>
> Create a mapping for `six.moves` called name that references different
>   modules in Python 2 and 3. `old_mod` is the name of the Python 2 module.
>   `new_mod` is the name of the Python 3 module.

However, this code yields an `ImportError` for me:

```
from six import add_move, MovedModule
add_move(MovedModule('mock', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'))
from six.moves.mock import MagicMock
```

When I run it on Python 3.4.2 using six 1.9.0 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_six_moves.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six.moves.mock import MagicMock
ImportError: No module named 'six.moves.mock'
```

The builtin moves are working just fine. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't import the name from within the move. Use:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from six import add_move, MovedModule
add_move(MovedModule('mock', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'))

from six.moves import mock
print(mock.MagicMock)
```

This will give you:

```
# Python 2
<class 'mock.MagicMock'>

# Python 3
<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
```

---

Note that importing from within a move works for the ones that ship with `six`. For example: `from six.moves.configparser import ConfigParser` works.

This piece of code (from [`six.py`](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/78315705481c3f5e491a3816e41aa66c54c8f965/six.py?at=default#cl-298)) is why:

```
for attr in _moved_attributes:
    setattr(_MovedItems, attr.name, attr)
    if isinstance(attr, MovedModule):
        _importer._add_module(attr, "moves." + attr.name)
```

In fact, if you ran the following (meddling with private attributes is of course not recommended), your import would work:

```
import six
mod = six.MovedModule('mock', 'mock', 'unittest.mock')
six.add_move(mod)
six._importer._add_module(mod, "moves." + mod.name)
```

Comment: Ah thanks, the fact that importing from within the moves works for builtins had me confused.

Comment: @BjörnPollex It's indeed a bit confusing that `add_move` doesn't do that for you. I'm sure there's a reason, though I don't know exactly what that is.

Comment: Cannot use `from six.moves.mock import Mock` really bother me. Till today I was using a packages structure like `portability.mock` and in `mock` copy all mock module by `from six.moves.mock import *`. Do the copy is even worst  and I'm really tempted to use `_importer` private access ... just a note: on ubuntu 14,04 python 3 comes with `six` 1.5.2 and that trick doesn't work

Comment: Btw, I have created an issue for this on the six project: [#116](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issue/116/enable-importing-from-within-custom).