# Introspection for custom six.moves modules

Tags: python, pycharm, six

To assist with migrating a Django project from Python 2 to Python 3, I've added a snippet of code to expose the moving of `mock` to `unittest.mock`.

The code seems to work when running the tests. It's not complete, but it covers the attributes that I use.

However, when viewing the imports in PyCharm, there's no type hinting, probably because the built in typeshed hints don't know about my custom moves.

```
from six.moves import mock  # for mock.ANY
from six.moves.mock import patch, PropertyMock, Mock
```

In the above example, PyCharm will underline `mock` (on both lines), `patch`, `PropertyMock` and `Mock` because it doesn't know about them.

Since I'm a bit pedantic, I'd consider creating the required .pyi files to go with, but I can't find too much about them, where they should sit in the code base and what they should look like.

My question what can I do to provide a .pyi or similar so that PyCharm knows about those definitions.

I've considered a possible solution might be to do a custom module for my `six` usage for these particular moves. i.e. `from lib.six.moves.mock import Mock` and my `lib/six/__init__.py` contains the code and with a `lib/six/moves/mock/__init__.pyi` with imports for the type hinting. The only thing is that I might want to restrict this to Python 2 and have another .pyi for Python 3, whilst the project has to run under both versions.

Following is the sample code that is living in the Django project `__init__.py`, so that it gets included everywhere. This is probably overkill, as it should only be needed for unit tests, but I couldn't locate a satisfactory place.

```
import six

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/28215387/343614
# six.add_move only provides part of the solution

moved_module = six.MovedModule('mock', 'mock', 'unittest.mock')
six.add_move(moved_module)
six._importer._add_module(moved_module, "moves." + moved_module.name)


class Module_six_moves_mock(six._LazyModule):
    """Lazy loading of moved objects in six.moves.mock"""


_mock_moved_attributes = [
    six.MovedAttribute('ANY', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'),
    six.MovedAttribute('call', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'),
    six.MovedAttribute('MagicMock', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'),
    six.MovedAttribute('Mock', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'),
    six.MovedAttribute('patch', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'),
    six.MovedAttribute('PropertyMock', 'mock', 'unittest.mock'),
]

for attr in _mock_moved_attributes:
    setattr(Module_six_moves_mock, attr.name, attr)
del attr

Module_six_moves_mock._moved_attributes = _mock_moved_attributes

six._importer._add_module(Module_six_moves_mock('six.moves.mock'), 'moves.mock', 'moves.unittest.mock')
```